# Changing an input type image to a link

Tags: input, hyperlink

I am looking to change this:

```
<input type=image 
   src="../images/btn.gif" 
   name="Old-#HTMLEditFormat(Address)#" 
   alt="Switch to Old" border=0>
```

To just a link, removing the image. 
What do I do for input type to make the image go away and the link work?

The language is ColdFusion and I want it to say "Switch to Old"

Thanks!

Comment: The language is Coldfusion, I just need the link to say "Switch to Old" without an image

Comment: Okay I did, sorry I'm new at this haha!

Comment: I don't think the `<input type=image ... >` makes links

Comment: Remove CF tag, as the question is strictly about html.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't use an `INPUT` anymore, you'd just use an `A` tag with the `title` attribute.

> <a href="some.cfm" title="Switch to Old">Some text</a>

An `INPUT` of type `IMAGE` is an alternate to one of type `SUBMIT`. So if you want a link to submit your existing form, then you'll need to assign an `ONCLICK` event to the link, which would call some JavaScript to submit the form.